# Как создать поле класса в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

нигде не нашел пытался по разному, никак. В интернете ничего не нашел.

```js
class Animal {
    public color;
    public constructor(color){
        this.color = color;
    }
}
var cat = new Animal("red");
alert(cat.color);
```

Comment: пока объявления полей не поддерживаются, только методы. возможно в следующих версиях языка ведут поддержку

Comment: Будем надеятся.

Comment: @Duoxx можно юзать typescript. там всё есть)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^^"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, у вас не работает код? Уберите `public`.

```js
class Animal {
    constructor(color){
        this.color = color;
    }
}
var cat = new Animal("red");

console.log(cat.color); // выведет red
```

Answer (score 1):

Само создаствся при присваивании. Но лучше все поля создавать в конструкторе в одном и том же порядке, чтобы всякие оптимизации в разных местах работали.

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(color){
    this.color = color;
  }
}

var cat = new Animal("red");
console.log(cat.color);
```

Comment: а вот если полей 10 нужно? не пихать же всё в конструктор :(

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, именно туда и пихать - а почему собственно нет-то?

Comment: Обычно так отвечает Grundy :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, нас почти раскрыли :-D